How to save into DB a column containing 'ISO8601 strings' as a format in Laravel migration
Is it possible to save a column as ISO8601 format that is not a string type?
Basically, I want to save the date and time as shown below:
2024-11-21T19:30:00.
I tried to use timestamp, so
$table->timestamp('start');
but it saves the data as 2024-11-21 19:30:00, so not as I want.
Is there a way to save it directly or do I have to use string, so $table->string('start') ?

I'd recommend leaving them as timestamps, as it's easier to search and compare. You can format them with Eloquent's date casting

So to have the format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS what do you recommend I use?

The value you're saving to the database should be a timestamp, like you have it now. If you wanted to store the ISO8601 value alongside it as a string, you could do that, but not sure what benefit you'd get out of that. When you actually use this value in your Laravel app, with a bit of configuration, you can simply do $model->start->toIso8601String() to display that value while keeping the correct value in the database.

One way to go about it is to treat it as a string and call the Carbon object to parse it to ISO8601 format when you need it.

So to have the format YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS what do you recommend I use?

To have this in the format mentioned above, you can also use Carbon object on the date you are working with at the time and call the ->toIso8601String() method on it to return the date in the format above. i.e $date_var = Carbon::parse(//your date); $date_var->toIso8601String(); which will return the date in the format you want.
